# Can't find a replacement SMD capacitor - markings 100 16v VD

Tags: capacitor, identification

I'm trying to replace an SMD capacitor in the echo sounder for my bait boat, which I use for fishing. The problem I'm having is finding a replacement. I've searched the internet and messaged a few of the large suppliers with no luck at all.

Would you possibly be able to recommend an alternative or where I would be able to get one from? The numbers and letters on the capacitor are "100 16v VD". It's 10.4 mm high and 11.3 mm dia.

Comment: From the letters you say it would be  a 100uF 16v capacitor, they are quite easy to find actually (look for aluminum electrolytic), also a picture would be nice as it may provide some extra information you didn't think of. Also the dimensions you wrote, assuming they are right and not flipped, are not quite standard, however you can find very similar sized ones

Answer (score 2):

As you gave a diameter, and only being in the ultrasonic range, I would presume it is a normal electrolytic (common black or silver cylinder capacitor),

I am confident that you could replace it with just about any capacitor with the same or higher voltage rating and same capacitance rating (16V or higher, e.g. 35V, and 100uF) providing it still fits in the same location

I would avoid trying to match the exact same height rather focus on a similar diameter so it mounts on the same pads.

For not much additional cost, I might suggest a "bi-polar" varient of the capacitor you choose if your not 100% sure which way it was on the PCB it was mounted, this just means it does not matter what orientation you reconnect it to the PCB, and means that its much harder for you to go wrong.

I cannot suggest a specific product due to the rules, but the common suppliers do let you sort this stuff by package size, e.g. digikey as the first supplier off the top of my head.